# NA values causing problems in summarise() even when using rm.na = TRUE

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to take the mean of some data with NA values, and I would like the NA values to be ignored. A reproducible example would be:

> ```
>      country      gdp
> 1    Austria    25.17
> 2 Azerbaijan       NA
> 3 Bangladesh    27.79
> 4    Belarus       NA
> ```

```
testdf2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
     country = c("Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bangladesh", "Belarus"),
         gdp = c(25.17654, NA, 27.7971, NA)
)
```

I've tried `summarise()` using `rm.na = TRUE` and without

```
library(dplyr)
testdf2 %>% summarise(gdp_mean = mean(gdp))

testdf2 %>% summarise(gdp_mean = mean(gdp), rm.na = TRUE)
```

but I keep getting output that looks like this:

> ```
>   gdp_mean
> 1       NA
> ```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: `testdf2 %>% summarise(gdp_mean = mean(gdp, na.rm= TRUE))`

Comment: `rm.na = TRUE` should be `mean` argument and not `summarise`, so: `mean(gdp, rm.na = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a typo. I tried your code like this and it works: `rm.na` should be `na.rm`, and of course what @kwiscion mentioned in his comment!

```
testdf2 %>% summarise(gdp_mean = mean(gdp, na.rm = TRUE))
```